# MySQL insert with List Comprehensions

Tags: python, mysql, list, list-comprehension, executemany

I've been trying to convert most of my [mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) execute commands to be done in a single line by making use of List Comprehensions. An example of this is the following snippet:

```
def org(conn, cursor, target_org=None, target_sid=None):
    try:
        if target_sid is not None:
            target_org = [{"sid": target_sid}]
        cursor.executemany(
            "INSERT INTO `Orgs` (`sid`) VALUES (%s);",
            [[Org['sid']] for Org in target_org])
        conn.commit()

...
```

If I, however, wanted a MySQL query that had multiple columns to be filled such as

```
"INSERT INTO `Citizens`(`Handle`,`Org`,`Role`,`Rank`,`Visibility`,`Stars`,`Type`)VALUE(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
```

How could I implement a List Comprehension receiving a list `member` composed of lists with the data for each member to work with the executemany command like the example above?

For example, to grab the `Handle` column only it would look something like

```
[Mem['handle'] for Mem in member]
# (cursor.executemany must always have a list as second argument)
```

`member` sample:

```
[{'roles': [], 'rank': 'No SCB account', 'type': 'main', 'stars': 2, 'visibility': 'visible', 'sid': 'imperium', 'handle': 'freakyeagle'}, {'roles': [], 'rank': 'Fleet Member', 'type': 'main', 'stars': 1, 'visibility': 'visible', 'sid': 'imperium', 'handle': 'cadimus'}, {'roles': [], 'rank': 'Fleet Member', 'type': 'main', 'stars': 1, 'visibility': 'visible', 'sid': 'imperium', 'handle': 'belleal'}]
```

Comment: You can use mappings with `executemany`. why not something like this -> cursor.executemany( "INSERT INTO `Orgs` (`sid`) VALUES (%(sid)s);", target_org)

Comment: @sagarchalise I just tried that and it worked perfectly, thank you. Is that appliable to my second example, when I have multiple fields?

Comment: And why did you put (%(sid)s) instead of (%s) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mappings with  `executemany`. Interpolation will work based on your dictionary. Since your `target_org` is list of dictionary with  key 'sid' 
so you can do something like:

```
cursor.executemany( "INSERT INTO Orgs (sid) VALUES (%(sid)s);", target_org)
```

I think this will work for your second problem as well.

See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle for parameter in python db-api

Comment: If on the `member` list (composed of dictionaries) I have `mem['sid'] for mem in member` but I want `['sid']`to be associated with the Org column would I do `...(%(sid)s)` or `...(%(Org)s)`

Comment: If your key is 'sid' it should  be '%(sid)s'

Comment: Okay, got it, testing it out now.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting `There was a problem inserting member(s): (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),'Recruit','visible',0,'main'),\n('alixander','imperium',(),'Fleet Member','visi' at line 2")`

Comment: `cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO `Citizens` (`Handle`,`Org`,`Role`, "
                                  "`Rank`,`Visibility`,`Stars`,`Type`) VALUES "
                                  "(%(handle)s,%(sid)s,%(roles)s,%(rank)s,"
                                  "%(visibility)s,%(stars)s,%(type)s);", member)`

Comment: Please paste you 'member' variable sample on your question

Comment: Good idea, should have done that from the beginning, my bad. Added.

Comment: I think your empty list with 'roles' is creating a problem.

Comment: Darn it, I'll see if I can pre-process it somewhere else to make it be "None" when it's empty.

Comment: Okay, I treated the data so there are no empty lists, now this is coming along:
There was a problem inserting member(s): (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')

Comment: Please check what query  is executed. You may need more data treatment as well.

Comment: Was about to do that, this is what's being run:
b"INSERT INTO `Citizens` (`Handle`,`Org`,`Role`, `Rank`,`Visibility`,`Stars`,`Type`) VALUES \n('freakyeagle','imperium','None','No SCB account','visible',2,'main'),\n('cadimus','imperium','None','Fleet Member','visible',1,'main'),\n('belleal','imperium','None','Fleet Member','visible',1,'main'),\n('boodan','imperium','None','Fleet Member','visible',1,'main'),\n('thorias','imperium','None','Fleet Member','visible',1,'main'),\n('valkrie','imperium','None','Fleet Member','visible',1,'main'),

Comment: So, I fixed it today, it was some mysterious bug with my filters that I am yet to comprehend entirely, but it's fixed. Thank's a lot for the help and patience!